# How to keep socket visible after closing the connection?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, netstat

Is it possible to configure Linux to keep a tcp connection visible for netstat/lsof after being closed? (doesn't matter the connection state). 
I need to detect it with netstat/lsof but if the connection is very short, it's not detected.

The socket I cannot register seems to be the one that receives the first FIN

Comment: You're confusing socket and ports. Sockets are closed immediately when you close them. Ports can go into various post-connect states before closing. What you see in netstat are ports, not sockets.

Comment: @EJP Them my problem seems to be in detecting processes associated with ephemeral ports, because their states are very short. Is there any manner to detect the processes associated with those ephemeral ports?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which end closes the connection first.

The port that closes first (sends the first FIN) will be in the TIME_WAIT state for a little while, the default number of seconds is in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`, and is normally 60 seconds, so you can see these with netstat after the program has closed the socket.

You can tune that if you need to, `echo 120 >  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`

The peer port (the one that receives the first FIN) seem to be erased immediately once it have received the FIN and sends FIN from its end - I havn't found anything to tune that behavior.

Comment: The socket I cannot register seems to be the one that receives the first FIN, I'll specify at the question and wait for other ideas. Thanks.